# Get friend's IDs of my friends in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a table in my database called `users_friendships` which basically looks like the following:

```
id     uid1    uid2
-----  -----   -----
1      1       4
2      1       2
3      2       10
4      3       6
..     ..      ..
```

Through a query, I am already getting the friend's IDs of mine. `$myid` symbolizes the ID of me:

```
    // GET FRIENDS ID
    $friendsID = array();

    $my_friends = $mysql->prepare("
       SELECT CASE WHEN uid1 = ? THEN uid2 
       ELSE uid1 END AS uid 
       FROM users_friendships 
       WHERE uid1 = ? OR uid2 = ?
    ");
    $my_friends->bind_param('iii', $myid, $myid, $myid);
    $my_friends->execute();
    $my_friends_results = $my_friends->get_result();

    while($mf = $my_friends_results->fetch_array()) {

        $mfrid = $mf['uid'];
        $friendsID[] = $mfrid;

    }
```

I am saving them in an array, can I somehow use this to set up a query for friends of my friends?

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Could you explain that a little deeper?

Comment: could you use `COALESCE()` instead of the condition, just a thought I had.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mostly reuse your existing code, looping on your array of friends:

```
$friendsoffriendsID = array();
foreach ($friendsID as $friendID) {
    $my_friends->bind_param('iii', $friendID, $friendID, $friendID);
    $my_friends->execute();
    $my_friends_results = $my_friends->get_result();
    while($mf = $my_friends_results->fetch_array()) {
        $mfrid = $mf['uid'];
        $friendsoffriendsID[] = $mfrid;
    }
}
```

This will undoubtedly give you a lot of duplicates, so you may want to just get the unique values using array_unique:

```
$friendsoffriendsID = array_unique($friendsoffriendsID);
```